# create multiple objects with loop in constructor function

Tags: javascript

I have a problem when trying to create multiple objects in the function of a constructor function.

I'm trying to create multiple objects that each one has the array hand, and each one has the name `player(x)`, so it would be `player0: [array]`, `player1:[array]`, but it does not work. I get the error

> Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Code:

```
function Player () {
  this.hand = []
}

function Players () {

}

Players.prototype.createPlayers = function (x) {
    for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
      this.player[i] = new Player()
  }
}

let gamer = new Players()
console.log(gamer)

gamer.createPlayers(3)
console.log(gamer.players)
```

Comment: You never create a `player` property on a `Players` instance

Comment: add `this.player = [];` in `Players` constructor

Comment: but i create it on the protoype that it loops and creates a new object

Comment: you need to initalize array before using it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: i would like to create it directly on the object and each object will have a different name of player1: [hand], player2: hand, and not in an extra array

Comment: I suspect you were looking for `this['player'+i] = new Player()`, but really you should drop that whole `Players` class which is just an elaborate array and write only `const gamers = Array.from({length: 3}, () => new Player()); console.log(gamers); console.log(gamers[0].hand);`

Comment: okey but can I make just a player class and in this class create amount of players?

Answer (score 1):

This is working try it, Is this you want?

```
function Player () {
  this.hand = []
}

function Players () {
  this.player = [];
}

Players.prototype.createPlayers = function (x) {
    for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
      this.player[i] = new Player()
  }
}

let gamer = new Players()
console.log(gamer)

gamer.createPlayers(3)
console.log(gamer.players)
```